# create a unordered list in jsf (ul)

Tags: jsf

Hi I need to implement a unordered list in jsf - just wondering if I have to create a custom tag for this ? I have tried using `<ul>` but it is currently falling outside of the jsf component tree. Cheers

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.2? JSF 2.0? JSPs? Facelets?

Comment: @brandizzi: What difference would it make if I'm using JSF 2.0 with facelets ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If @johnathan uses JSF 2 with Facelets, its views are just XHTML with some other namespaces (such as "f" and "h") for JSF components. In this case, he can use  ul and li tags as they are used in XHTML. This is not the case with JSP because the JSF components are tags from taglibs, rendered in a different phrase from the one where bare JSP output (such as HTML tags) is added to resulting page.

Answer (score 5):

> *but it is currently falling outside of the jsf component tree*

This suggests that you're using the legacy JSF 1.0/1.1. See for more detail also [JSF/Facelets: why is it not a good idea to mix JSF/Facelets with HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474178/jsf-facelets-why-is-it-not-a-good-idea-to-mix-jsf-facelets-with-html-tags/7320873#7320873)

You've basically 3 options:

1. Upgrade to JSF 1.2. It has exactly the same environmental requirements as JSF 1.0/1.1 and would thus not require any other changes, just replacing the JARs would suffice. Once done that, you can write down "plain HTML" without any trouble.

   ```html
   <ul>
       <li>item 1</li>
       <li>item 2</li>
       <li>item 3</li>
   </ul>
   ```

   ---
2. If upgrading is really not an option, which would be really strange, then wrap blocks of plain HTML in `<f:verbatim>`.

   ```html
   <f:verbatim>
       <ul>
           <li>item 1</li>
           <li>item 2</li>
           <li>item 3</li>
       </ul>
   </f:verbatim>
   ```

   Note that you don't necessarily need to wrap every individual tag. Only close and reopen it when you encounter a JSF component "halfway". Even the following is valid.

   ```html
   <f:verbatim>
       <ul>
           <li>item 1</li>
           <li></f:verbatim><h:outputText value="#{bean.some}" /><f:verbatim></li>
           <li>item 3</li>
       </ul>
   </f:verbatim>
   ```

   ---
3. Use a JSF 1.0/1.1 compatible component library which offers a component out the box which generates a `<ul><li>`. Only one comes to mind: [Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/) [`<t:dataList>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_dataList.html). Just set its `layout` attribute to `unorderedlist` to get it to generate an `<ul><li>`.

   ```html
   <t:dataList layout="unorderedList" value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
       <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
   </t:dataList>
   ```

Comment: Would ui:repeat with <li> inside not be an option too?

Answer (score 0):

Very crude - I know but just settled for the good old:

```
<f:verbatim> tag e.g. `
<f:verbatim><ul></f:verbatim>
<f:verbatim><li></f:verbatim>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<f:verbatim></li></f:verbatim>
<f:verbatim><li></f:verbatim>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<f:verbatim></li></f:verbatim>
<f:verbatim><li></f:verbatim>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<f:verbatim></li></f:verbatim>
<f:verbatim><li></f:verbatim>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<f:verbatim></li></f:verbatim>
<f:verbatim><li></f:verbatim>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<f:verbatim></li></f:verbatim>
<f:verbatim></ul><f:verbatim>`
```

Comment: AFAIK you don't need f:verbatim for custom HTML anymore (starting from JSF 1.2).

Comment: @Kawu can we directly write the html in f:view if working with facelets & JSF 2.0.?

Comment: Just try it, I do it all the time. It's a myth from JSF 1.0 times to not mix JSF and HTML tags. Now that I have also made my progress you should definitely look into using RichFaces or some similar advanced GUI lib. Ever since I punched myself into using one I don't regret a single line of code (that I effectively saved, because others did all the work)...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to embed every start tag, inner text, and end tag in a distinct `<f:verbatim>`. You can simply do this:

```
<f:verbatim>
<ul>
 <li>foo</li>
 <li>bar</li>
 <li>baz</li>
</ul>
</f:verbatim>
```

Alternatively you can use Facelets which handles interleaving of JSF and HTML tags like a charm.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use facelets with JSF 2.0. Is including the html within `f:verbatim` tags also required for my case? Thanks!

Comment: @Marcos: In Facelets the `f:verbatim` is not required at all. `f:verbatim` is only needed when you use JSF inside JSP pages.