# JSF/Facelets: why is it not a good idea to mix JSF/Facelets with HTML tags?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, facelets

I've read this several times now: some developers aren't advocates of interleaving JSF/Facelets tags with HTML tags in their XHTML files. Obviously the HTML tags won't be part of the UI component tree, but what's the disadvantage of that?

I often find code examples where the authors do that kind of mixing:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/

http://www.packtpub.com/article/facelets-components-in-jsf-1.2

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529246

"Seam in Action" also interleaves JSF/Facelets and HTML tags.

I'm confused about what to actually use. I started out mixing tags, but I'm beginning to believe it was probably not the right choice. However, I fail to see why the puristic approach is preferrable.

I know for certain that I have a table where the JSF datatable doesn't give me enough flexibility to display what I need to, so doing it puristically isn't possible.

Furthermore I'm wondering why none of the examples above use f:view etc. instead of the hardcoded html, head, body etc. tags.

Can anyone please clear this up for me?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375821/when-should-i-use-jsf-components-and-when-should-i-use-html-tags/5376344#5376344) regarding JSF/HTML tags

Comment: OK this helps. At least regarding div and span, but how do I manage p, br, and especially headings?

Comment: From my answer in the referenced question: "In practice I found it hard to follow this recommendation and ended up mixing html and jsf, e.g. for headings or line breaks I use html."

Comment: Hmmm disappointing. Shouldn't there be a JSF way?

Comment: I don't see why this isn't a good idea and that this is disappointing. Maybe you're victim of the myth that mixing JSF+HTML=bad which was caused during JSF 1.0/1.1 ages? For more history, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273595/jsf-vs-htmljsp-for-enterprise-portals-ui-layer-which-one-to-choose-and-why/3274299#3274299

Answer (score 20, accepted):

During the JSF 1.0/1.1 ages this was indeed "not a good idea", because all the HTML was not automatically taken in the JSF component tree when using JSP as view technology. All plain HTML was eagerly by JSP rendered *before* the JSF component tree. E.g.

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum <h:outputText value="#{bean.value1}"> dolor sit amet<p>
<p>Consectetur adipiscing <h:inputText value="#{bean.value2}" /> elit</p>
```

got rendered as

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<p>
<p>Consectetur adipiscing elit</p>

value1
<input type="text" value="value2" />
```

To fix this you would need to bring `<f:verbatim>` in.

```html
<f:verbatim><p>Lorem ipsum </f:verbatim><h:outputText value="#{bean.value1}"><f:verbatim> dolor sit amet<p></f:verbatim>
<f:verbatim><p>Consectetur adipiscing </f:verbatim><h:inputText value="#{bean.value2}" /><f:verbatim> elit</p></f:verbatim>
```

This was a real maintenance pain. This was one of the major reasons why JSF 1.0/1.1 was so hated.

Since JSF 1.2, with the new view handler, the `<f:verbatim>` was not necessary anymore. Developers can now breathe relieved. Moreover, the new view handler allowed JSF to use a different view technology than JSP and this way Facelets was born.

#### See also:

- [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0)
- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o/)
- [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5)
- [JavaServer Faces 2.2 and HTML5 support, why is XHTML still being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189372/javaserver-faces-2-2-and-html5-support-why-is-xhtml-still-being-used)

Comment: +1 for concise explanation and perfect example.  I knew this before hand but really well put.

Comment: Note that there may be a minor performance advantage in using plain html instead of components that give the same result (div vs t:div) , as that  reduces parsing time. Know however that html tags are not contained as components in the view root (afaik)

Comment: @Steven: It has no influence on view build time. It's parsed and inspected anyway (and converted to specialized `UIInstructions` components). Only view render time may be significantly faster if you've relatively a lot of them as they're rendered as "template text" without any state and attributes (but still with EL evaluation support).

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, I use a mix betweek HTML and Facelets tags in the layout/template pages. But for the actual content pages I try to only use the JSF tags available with my JSF library of choice (JSF + RichFaces).

That way I can have more control of which elements to show and hide, as well as the contents within each element, but I can still hard-code my main page layout in the facelets template file.