# Is it advised to combine: JSF 2.0 + Facelets + HTML5/CCS3/JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, twitter-bootstrap, facelets

I recently started developing a web application using JSF 2.0, however I'm new to web development and the field (even when limiting to JVM solutions) is turning out to be vast... the number of technologies to choose between is a bit overwhelming.

My concern/question is this, is it feasible/advised to mix/integrate the following technologies?

- CCS3 + HTML5 + JavaScript (particularly, using Twitter Bootstrap framework)
- JSF 2.0
- Facelets

And if so, when working with a web designer what are the things that JSF 2.0 is going to make more difficult for me. For example, when integrating the web design into the application I guess I'll have to do some modifications: inserting JSF tags and EL expressions, deal with JavaScript in some special way(?), working through HTML tags incompatibilities(?), etc.

The following questions were helpful, but have not clarified everything:

- [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0)
- [JSF/Facelets: why is it not a good idea to mix JSF/Facelets with HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474178/jsf-facelets-why-is-it-not-a-good-idea-to-mix-jsf-facelets-with-html-tags)
- [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You seem to not fully understand the point of JSF. JSF is basically just a HTML/CSS/JS code producer. It really doesn't matter to JSF what version the produced code is. JSF doesn't run in webbrowser or something. It runs in webserver. All the webbrowser retrieves is just the JSF-produced HTML/CSS/JS code. You just have to make sure that *that* HTML/CSS/JS code is understood by the particular webbrowser.

Comment: Imagine this scenario... web designer creates a "pretty page" (HTML/CSS/JS) for me -> I then bind client side user behavior from that "pretty page" to my "server side logic" (JSF/Java) -> to do that I need to add templating tags (JSF/Facelet/JSTL/EL) to the "pretty page"... my question is, are there known difficulties that often occur during this step, which I should be aware of)

Comment: Or are you telling me that it's impossible to design the "pretty page" external to JSF, because JSF wants to do ALL the CSS/HTML/JS itself?

Comment: You can easily use `<ui:composition>` to form templates. And no, JSF doesn't require you to use JSF components only.