# How to align images horizontally with JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm sure this a duplicate but what I found here and elsewhere on the net just didn't work for me.

Whatever I do, the images in the following code are aligned vertically, but I want them horizontally.

```
<script>
    var aa = "src='images/img?r=' + Math.random()"
    var bb = "src='images/trans?x=' + Math.random()"
</script>
<hr />

<h:panelGroup layout="horizontal">
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink>
            <h:graphicImage width="100" id="img1"
                value="images/img?r=1#{Math.random()}" alt="not found">
            </h:graphicImage>
            <f:ajax render="@this :pg2"></f:ajax>
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="pg2">
        <h:graphicImage width="100" id="img2"
            value="images/trans?y=#{Math.random()}" onclick="eval(bb)">
        </h:graphicImage>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:messages></h:messages>
<hr />
```

(And don't get confused about that #{Math.random()}. It works just because I have a bean called "Math".)

I'm using tomcat 8 and jsf version 2.2.8.

Comment: Please post screenshot if possible

Comment: Meta-question: I see surprising reputation changes. one downvote, then an upvote. If you people want me to improve performance/behavior, I need to learn about the reasons, especially for downvotes. What have I done wrong, how should I improve?

Comment: i was surprised too by -1 and upvoted your question. I got everything i needed for me to answer. i don't see how you could have given <b>more</b> info

Comment: I feel there are many downvotes, not just to me, out of "unclean" reasons. I hold that every downvoter should be forced by the stackexchange-framework to leave a comment. Hit out of the dark and run is not helpful for no one.

Comment: @gyrogearloose: if you hover over the downvote, you see a 'reason' (and no I did not downvote). One of the 'to little effort' things is that you did not mention what you tried and why it did not work. Mentioning things like this is what is requested in [ask]. Mentioning version info is also requested.

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't understand that "hover over the downvote" part. When I hover over the up/downvote arrows attatched to the original question, I see general hints for why anyone should up or down-vote, but no information why anyone did. I have no experience in downvoting, but when I upvoted (sparesly, I would not want to start an inflation) I was never asked to give any reason. Perhaps I should have a try on downvoting someone randomly just for the feel of it? (Just joking. For now, at least.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
 <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="210px" columnClasses="small, small">
     <h:panelGroup id="a1">
       <h:form>
        <h:commandLink>
           <h:graphicImage width="100" id="img1"
            value="images/img?r=1#{Math.random()}" alt="not found">
          </h:graphicImage>
          <f:ajax render="@this :pg2"></f:ajax>
        </h:commandLink>
     </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="b1">
     <h:form id="pg2">
       <h:graphicImage width="100" id="img2"
        value="images/trans?y=#{Math.random()}" onclick="eval(bb)">
       </h:graphicImage>
     </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
  </h:panelGrid>
```

with CSS:

```
 .small{
      width:102px;
      vertical-align: text-top;
 }
```

Let us know

Edit. changed div to panelGroup

Comment: Thanks, but still one image is displayed above the other. I really wonder if there is a way to UNDERSTAND all that stuff, looks like nearly everyone works by try and error. Online tutorials don't explain much, and the documentation from oracle is plain awful.

Comment: panelGrids are rendered as html tables. so columns="2", guarantees two columns. A screenshot would be nice.

Comment: When I replace the "div"-tags from your code by "h:panelGroup" it works! But I don't understand why it didn't work with the (oh, so many) other versions.

Comment: Great. Edited my answer too. please. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cos6/index.html might be of help

Comment: Already done. A last thing, it should be width="210" instead of width="210px".

Comment: Note: Using tables for layout is bad practice. There CSS should be used for.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `display: inline-block` style to the second form

as you see in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/wZB9z/) the images need to be inside divs which contain this css

Comment: Like this <h:form id="pg2" style="display: inline-block"> ? Still one atop of the other.

Comment: As I'm a novice, I had some try and error on where to put the style.css. It finaly worked, but it seems strange that I do need HTML tags.

Comment: If you are a novice to jsf, make sure you have a descent html and css knowledge. If you look at the generated html, very often the correct css is easy to create and not a jsf thing

Comment: @Kukeltje hit nail on head. Gyro, it seems that you didn't had the chance to learn basic HTML and CSS before using JSF to generate HTML and CSS, or perhaps even didn't realize that JSF is basically a HTML/CSS generator. I strongly recommend to take a JSF pause and learn basic HTML/CSS first. http://htmldog.com has nice tutorials.

Comment: @Gyro: *"It finaly worked, but it seems strange that I do need HTML tags."* This also gives me the impression that you learned JSF the wrong way. Perhaps you started with a decade-old JSF 1.x targeted learning resource. Please throw away it. None of this all is true for modern web development with JSF 2.x. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5474178

Comment: @BalusC you are right, but I never wanted to use html-tags with jsf, instead I asked in surprise why I would have to do so to make it work. And to your comment above about using CSS and avoiding tables, I'm not sure what (minimal) structures I need to make the <f:ajax> work. I haven't found a proper description yet and have to rely on try&error, sadly.

Comment: I totally fail to see the relation f:ajax here. And for f:ajax, there are douzens of good tuturials, so I fail to see that problem to