# How to replace tomhawk htmltag as we want to remove tomahawk from the project

Tags: jsf, tomahawk, jakarta-migration

We are migrating because tomahawk is not supporting jakarata-ee

```
<t:htmlTag value="ul">
    <t:htmlTag value="li">
        <h:commandLink action="searchPage" id="search" forceId="true">
            <h:outputText value="&nbsp;&nbsp;#{bean.menu_search}" escape="false" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </t:htmlTag>
    <t:htmlTag value="ul">
        <t:htmlTag value="li" style="display: none;">
            <h:commandLink id="search_results" forceId="true"
                action="searchResultsPage">
                <h:outputText value="&nbsp;&nbsp;#{bean.menu_selection}"
                    escape="false" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </t:htmlTag>
    </t:htmlTag>
```

We are using jakarta faces and prime faces in project

Answer (score 2):

The `<t:htmlTag>` is basically a leftover of JSF 1.0 when it wasn't possible to embed plain vanilla HTML in a JSF page without fiddling with `<f:verbatim>` tags. The `<t:htmlTag>` made it less opaque.

However, since JSF 1.2 it's not necessasy anymore to use `<f:verbatim>` let alone `<t:htmlTag>` in order to embed plain vanilla HTML in a JSF page. You can just use plain vanilla HTML right away.

In other words, the replacement of

```xml
<t:htmlTag value="ul">
    ...
</t:htmlTag>
```

would simply have been the plain vanilla HTML tag represented by the `value` attribute of the original `<t:htmlTag>` component:

```html
<ul>
    ...
</ul>
```

#### See also:

- [JSF/Facelets: why is it not a good idea to mix JSF/Facelets with HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474178/jsf-facelets-why-is-it-not-a-good-idea-to-mix-jsf-facelets-with-html-tags)
- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o)

Comment: How to handle below :

<h:htmlTag value="li" style="display: none;"
    rendered="#{!empty bean.selectedId}">
    <h:commandLink id="bean" forceId="true"
     action="beanPage">
     <h:outputText value="&nbsp;&nbsp;#{msg.menu_content}"
      escape="false" />
    </h:commandLink>
   </h:htmlTag>

Comment: Use `<ui:fragment rendered="..."><li>...</li></ui:fragment>` or `<li jsf:id="foo" rendered="...">`.

Comment: It worked. I have used <ul><li></li></ul>

Comment: That's indeed conform the answer.